# Dataframe length PySpark

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pyspark, aws-glue

I am working with AWS, s3, Glue and PySpark and wanted to load a csv file from s3. However, I noticed that the length of the file is different if I load it with PySpark than if I use Python or R. Do you know what could be happening? Below is my code:

```
df = glueContext.read.load(
    "s3://bucketname/file_name.csv",
    format="csv",
    sep="|",
    header="true"
    )
df = df.toDF(*df.columns)
df.count()
```

in Python

```
import boto3
import datatable as dt

def readS3(fileName, s3_instance, bucketName='bucketname'):
    return dt.fread(s3_instance.Object(bucketName,fileName).get()['Body'].read()) 

s3 = boto3.resource('s3') 
df = readS3("file_name.csv", s3)
```

in R

```
df <- s3_read("s3://bucketname/file_name.csv", data.table::fread)
```

Comment: Could you provide an example of loading via Python, which results in a different file size?

Comment: Yes, sure`import boto3
import datatable as dt

def readS3(fileName, s3_instance, bucketName='bucketname'):
    return dt.fread(s3_instance.Object(bucketName,fileName).get()['Body'].read())

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
df = readS3("file_name.csv", s3)`

Comment: I am curious if the python version is different because of the `.get()['Body'].read()` portion. Perhaps the other methods are reading more than just the "Body" of the file. Does that version result in a file that is *smaller* or *larger* than the others?